# How does one execute a for loop inside of a function (on a function)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, random

I'm working on creating a generic "lorem ipsum" generator in pure JavaScript. I've managed to get it working to a point where it'll pull from an array of lower-case strings in an array, joining them with a space, capitalizing the first one and putting a period a the end.

I also have it set up to a point where these sentences get pushed to a larger array and joined into a paragraph. However, I can't get the sentence generation and array push to loop any more than once inside of the function. Multiple calls to the global function will result in an appending the last sentence generated to the paragraph, however I'd like to be able to generate a random number of sentences and push them to the array on each subsequent call to the global function (and in the future, use this same pattern to generate a random number of paragraphs).

Perhaps its obvious what I'm doing wrong, but I thought calling a for-loop inside of the global function on the sentence generating function would work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ipsum.js"></script>
    <title>Generic Ipusm</title>
</head>
<input type="button" id="make" value="Make" onclick="makeParagraphs();" />
<p id="message" >Click to generate!</p>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
var arr = [];
var arr = ["this","array","of","random","words"];
var paragraph = [];

function makeParagraphs() {

  var message = [];
  var sentence;

  var paragrapher = paragraph.join(" ");
  console.log("p: " + paragrapher);
  var makeSentences = function() {

    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 5; // Words in sentence range
    for (i=1; i<=r; i++) {

      var random = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];  
      message.push(random);
      var words = message.join(" ") + ".";
      var sentencer = capitalize(words);
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = sentencer;


    }
    var sentence = sentencer;
    console.log("s: " + sentence);
    paragraph.push(sentence);

  }
  for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    makeSentences();
  }
}
```

The last call in the loop was my attempt to generate and push 4 sentences to the paragraph. Is there a limitation in the language preventing me from calling a function multiple times like so?

Here's a fiddle (Bear in mind I'm logging the paragraph result to the console, the only text appearing in the DOM itself is the result of the last sentence generated):

http://jsfiddle.net/kmblackwood/8dvNc/

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to do, but `document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = sentencer;` will overwrite anything currently in `message`. (Oh, and people have answered about implicit globals; use strict mode and a linter to solve that.)

Comment: Why do you declare the `arr` variables two times? (lines 4 and 5) You can remove the first one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dvNc/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a limitation in the language preventing me from calling a function multiple times like so?

No. The problem is that you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `i`. Right now, the `i` in your `makeSentences` is an implicit global, and so your loop at the end is being affected by it. That is, the `i` in your `for` loop at the end and the `i` in your `for` loop within `makeSentences` end up being the **same** (global) variable, `i`. So when your `for` loop at the end calls `makeSentences` the first time, `makeSentences` changes `i` to a value greater than `4` and your `for` loop at the end terminates. (You're missing a declaration for `r`, too.)

You might also consider using "strict mode" so that any decent JavaScript engine (like that in any modern browser) would tell you about the implicit global. Strict mode tells the engine that writing to an undefined symbol should be an error, not create an implicit global.

You enable strict mode by putting this:

```
 "use strict";
```

...at the top of a file or script block. It applies to everything within that file or script block.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not doing `var i;` in your `makeSentences` function, so it's polluting the parent scope and corrupting your other loop.